# In the proof of the Kodaira Embedding theorem

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

I'am reaidng complex manifold course : [https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~cschnell/pdf/notes/complex-manifolds.pdf](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ecschnell/pdf/notes/complex-manifolds.pdf),

p. 100 Kodaira embedding theorem :

[image]

[image]

I'm now trying to understand the underlined statements.'

Here, the author define the positive holomorphic line bundle as follows (p.92)

**Def.** A holomorphic line bundle $L\to M$ is positive if its first Chern class $c_1(L)$ can be represented by  a closed (1,1)-form $\Omega$ whose associated Hermitian form is positive definite.

1. For the first underlined statement, why such large integer $l$ exists?
   I found associated question :  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37827/tensor-product-of-a-line-bundle-with-a-large-multiple-of-another-positive-line-b
   But any one can explain more in detail?
2. For the second statement, why $\pi^{*}(L^{l}\otimes K_{M}^{-1}) \otimes (\tilde{L}^{m}\otimes [-E])^n $ is positive?
   (Here $[-E]$ means the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{M}}(-E)$)

Q.2-1) Pull back of positive line bundle under the blow up is also positive?

Q.2-2) The tensor product of positive line bundles is also positive?

If so, why?

If furthure information is needed, I will upload continuosly

Can anyone helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to bypass our problem. Although $\pi^{*}(L^{l}\otimes K_{M}^{-1})$ may not be positive,  the $P_k := \pi^{*}(L^k \otimes K^{-1}_M)\otimes [-E]^n$ in the above image is positive for $k>>0$ by the Heybrechts's Complex Geometry, Lemma 5.3.2 :

[image]

So the below argument(underlined statements) is not needed.