# Is the map associated to the blow up of a point in a complex manifold an immersion?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I have a question :

> Let $\sigma : \hat{X}:=\operatorname{Bl}_p(X) \to X $ be the blow up of $X$ at $p \in X$. ($X$ can be compact and Kahler)

Let's see the next imame (Huybrechts's *Complex Geometry*, p.100)

[image]

Then is $\sigma$ an immersion? i.e., is each pushforward map
$\sigma_{*,x'} : T_{x'}\hat{X} \to T_{\sigma(x')}X$ injective for all $x' \in \hat{X}$?

If further information about blowing up is needed, I will upload continuously.

Comment: What does $\sigma$ look like when restricted to the exceptional divisor $\sigma^{-1}(p)$?

Comment: Uhm.. $\mathbb{P} ^{n-1} \to X $. I don't know yet what this map looks like concretely. Furthur investigation is needed.

Comment: You can say more than that. It is a particularly simple map (what is $\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(p))$?)

Comment: Oh, I mistake. $\mathbb{P}^{n-1} \to \{p\} $. Uhm..But how this is related to the issue of immersionness of the $\sigma$? I'll try to think somewat more

Comment: If $\sigma$ is an immersion, then its restriction to any submanifold is also an immersion. Is the map you describe (the restriction of $\sigma$ to the exceptional divisor) an immersion?

Comment: Yes. Let $\pi : \mathbb{P}^{n-1} \to {p}$. For each $p' \in \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, $\operatorname{dim}(T_{\pi (p')} \{p\}) = 0 $ since ${p}$ is a zero dimensional submanifold. But $ \operatorname{dim} \mathbb{P}^{n-1} = n-1 $. So there is a possibility of violation of the immersionness of $\pi$.

Comment: Exactly, $\sigma$ is not an immersion when restricted to the exceptional divisor, so $\sigma$ is not an immersion. Away from the exceptional divisor it is though, in fact it is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Yes, maybe the blowing up $\sigma$ induces an isomorphism $\hat{X} - \sigma^{-1}(\{p\}) \cong X-\{p\}$, where $X-\{p\}$ is open since $X$ is haussdorff. I edit our question so that it includes a original motivation. Perhaps..can you see?

Comment: At no point is it claimed that $\pi^*(L^l\otimes K_M^{-1})$ is positive (because it isn't). I think you should undo the edit. Either you or I can answer this question. The points you raise in your edit already feature in your linked questions.

Comment: Yes! Even if $\pi^{*}(L^l \otimes K_M^{-1})$ may not be positive, we can apply the the Huybrechts's Lemma 5.3.2. , which is key point and hard part to prove. I edit https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4407871/in-the-proof-of-the-kodaira-embedding-theorem for the associated issue. Thank's for comment~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was discussed in the comments, $\sigma$ is not an immersion if $\dim X > 1$ (if $\dim X = 1$ then $\sigma$ is a biholomorphism as mentioned in the image text). Along the exceptional divisor $\sigma^{-1}(p)$, the map $\sigma$ is just a constant map with value $p$. So for $q \in \sigma^{-1}(p)$, the tangent space $T_q\sigma^{-1}(p) \subset T_q\hat{X}$ maps to $T_p\{p\} = \{0\} \subset T_pX$. In particular, $\sigma_{*,q}$ is not injective if $\dim\sigma^{-1}(p) = \dim X - 1 > 0$; that is, $\sigma$ is not an immersion if $\dim X > 1$. On the other hand, for $q \notin \sigma^{-1}(p)$, the linear map $\sigma_{*,q}$ is an isomorphism as $\sigma$ is a biholomorphism when restricted to $\hat{X}\setminus\sigma^{-1}(p)$.

Comment: O.K. I see~ . Thanks for clearing it up !